# Failed to assign an array to a double pointer

Tags: c

this code compiles without problems but when I running it, this crashes and does not work.
I noticed and the error is in this part

```
EXTRAE_DATOS(nombre_alumno[i] , alias);
```

I do not know what's wrong, help please.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> //strlen
#include <stdio.h>

#define fila 2     //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< AQUI DESPUES HAY QUE CAMBIAR POR 500000, PUSE 2 PARA PROBAR CON 2 DATOS
#define columna 50

void EXTRAE_DATOS(char *variable, FILE *file);

int main()
{
    FILE *alias;
    alias = fopen("datos.txt","r");
    if (alias == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError: El archivo 'datos.txt' no se ha encontrado.\n");
    }


    char **nombre_alumno; 

    int Matricula_alumno=1;

    nombre_alumno=(char**)malloc(fila*sizeof(char*));

    int i;

    //recorro el vector dinamico nombre_alumno para hacer vectores en cada uno de sus elementos
    for(i=0;i<fila;i++)
    {
        nombre_alumno[i]=(char*)malloc(columna*sizeof(char));
        if(nombre_alumno[i]==NULL)
        {
            printf("No se ha podido reservar memoria");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    //dandole valores a la primera matriz nombre_alumno
    for(i=0;i<fila;i++)
    {
        EXTRAE_DATOS(nombre_alumno[i] , alias);   // <<<<<<<<<<------------ AQUI ESTA EL PROBLEMA  
    }


    for(i=0;i<fila;i++)
    {

        printf("INSERT INTO ALUMNO VALUES (%d,'%s');\n",Matricula_alumno,nombre_alumno[i]);
        Matricula_alumno++;

    }

//Function to extract the data from the file
void EXTRAE_DATOS(char *variable, FILE *file)
{
    int fin_campo , i;
    char auxiliar[50];
    char caracter;

    i = 0;
    fin_campo = 0;

    while(fin_campo == 0)      //Lee todo un campo caracter por caracter.
    {
        caracter = fgetc(file);
        if((caracter == '\r' || caracter == ','))
        {
            fin_campo = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            auxiliar[i] = caracter;
            i++;
        }
    }
    auxiliar[i] = '\0';
    strcpy(variable , auxiliar);
}
```

I created a txt file called "datos" with this inside, just to prove:
**Zina,Bartley**

The original txt must have 50000 data.

Comment: We have to see `EXTRAE_DATOS` definition.

Comment: There's no definition given for `EXTRAE_DATOS`.  Where is it?

Comment: google and learn how to use a debugger - that's mandatory

Comment: ^ _"this code compiles without problems but when I running it, this crashes and does not work"_

Comment: Now i added extrae_datos

Comment: Do you know what line it is crashing on?

Comment: Use English also in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is infinite which means you are writing outside of bounds and that invokes undefined behavior.

To fix this you have to declare `caracter` as `int`.

Then you have to check whether `caracters` (after reading character from file) equals `EOF` or newline.

Change

```
if((caracter == '\r' || caracter == ','))
```

to

```
if((caracter == '\n' || caracter == ','))
```

and add check for EOF.

```
if (caracter == EOF) { return EOF; }

// In main exit loop after reaching EOF

if(EXTRAE_DATOS(nombre_alumno[i] , alias) == EOF) break;
```

Also dont forget to free allocated memory after printing.

**[Corrected code.](https://ideone.com/P9wUoZ)**

Comment: Thanks friend,it works :D

Comment: Try it now @RicardoBarros. You are welcome :-)

Comment: My bad, i fixed it, thanks again :) But I did not understand the part that you said "You have to declare character as int."
Why should i declare "character" as int? If I'm supposed to be reading characters from the txt file

Comment: Because EOF is `-1`. `-1` are only ones bitwise, If you store it to char variable, it cuts from 32/64 (architecture depended) to 8 bits. Then if you are comparing this character to EOF, character will expand to int (completed with zeros) which is not `-1` anymore and they wont never match. [Here(click)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197625/storing-the-eof-end-of-file-character-in-a-char-type) it is better explained :-)

Comment: I get it now, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You're not correctly detecting the end of the line:

```
    if((caracter == '\r' || caracter == ','))
    {
        fin_campo = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        auxiliar[i] = caracter;
        i++;
    }
```

On Linux machines, the newline character is `\n`, not `\r`.  As a result, you continue writing past the end of the `auxiliar` array, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to add a check for `\n`:

```
if((caracter == '\n' || caracter == '\r' || caracter == ','))
```

Also, you should change the type of `caracter` to `int`.  That way, you can check for `EOF` and break out of the loop in that case as well.  You should also check that `i` doesn't exceed the length of your string.

Comment: Additionally it would be good to check whether `i < 49`

Comment: I'm using windows bro :)

Comment: @RicardoBarros It doesn't matter what OS you are using, The newline character is `\n'.